# How to calculate the nullity for a matrix with variable?

Tags: linear-algebra

In order to find the number of (x,y) satisfying

$$f(x,y) =\begin{cases}
    xy^2-y+x^2+1=0\\
    x^2y^2+y-1=0\\
  \end{cases}$$

I use the Jacobi-Darboux Theorem by fix 1.x; 2.y and get the Bezoutian matrix, but I don't know how to find the nullity of the both matrix...

1. $$B = 
    \begin{pmatrix}
     y^3-y^2 & y^3-y^2+y-1\\
     y^3-y^2+y-1 & -y^4 
    \end{pmatrix}$$
2. $H_{f_x} = 
    \begin{pmatrix}
     -1 & x\\
     x & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, $T_{f_x} = 
    \begin{pmatrix}
     1+x^2 & -1\\
     0 & 1+x^2 \end{pmatrix}$, $H_{g_x} = 
    \begin{pmatrix}
     1 & -1-x\\
     -1-x & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, $T_{g_x} = 
    \begin{pmatrix}
     -1 & 1\\
     0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$

$$B = \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & -1-x\\
  -x & -x \end{pmatrix} - \begin{pmatrix}
  1+x^2 & -1+x^2+x^4\\
  x^2+x^4 & -x^2 \end{pmatrix}= 
 \begin{pmatrix}
  -x^2 & -x^4-x^2-x\\
  -x^4-x^2-x & x+x^2 
 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: What if you set the determinant of either equal to zero and solve the roots of the seventh-order equation, that is, solve one of the two for either the $x$ or the $y$ values and find three real and four imaginary roots.

Comment: I see. What if I really want to use Jacobi-Darboux Theorem? I want to use it in order to see if it is right.

Comment: I verified it provides correct results by doing what I suggest - at least I verified the $y$ matrix provides the correct $y$ values. I will try the $x$ matrix, something appears incorrect with it.

Comment: I mean this is the first time I use Jacobi-Darboux Theorem and I want to verified the theorem by solve the nullity. Also, I want to ask, is it reall have 3 real roots? I can only see y=1 or x=0 as a real root.

Comment: $x = 0, -0.82331624031681843600623791081631398446017107805108,
-0.42729694882092947334139625163239381903021338009365$, $ y = 1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, 
-2.1586638815282135283375942540489877838626875447372,  
  0.86377403967541686556594786092139789821785738258669$

Comment: Maybe you can add the details of your calculations for the two matrices as something appears incorrect about the second one.

Comment: Sure, I just type for the second case.

Answer (score 1):

We can solve the two polynomial equations using $S$-polynomials (from Buchberger's algorithm). Apart from the trivial solution $(x,y)=(0,1)$ this yields
$$
x=y^4 + y^3 - 2y^2 + y - 1,
$$
so that we obtain a polynomial in $y$, namely
$$
y^6 + y^5 - y^4 + 2y^3 - 2y^2 + y - 1=0.
$$
This has $6$ solutions over the complex numbers. Two of them are real solutions,
i.e., $y=0.863774039675$ and $y=- 2.15866388153$.

Comment: Which two of them are real? I just saw y=1 is one real root.