# How to tell if a system of polynomial equations has no real solutions

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, real-algebraic-geometry

I have a system of $3n + 3$ polynomial equations in $6n$ variables, where $n$ is probably going to be less than about $5$.  I can compute its Groebner basis and I see that it does not contain $\{1\}$, so I know that it has *complex* solutions at least.  However, I know for a fact that, by varying some of the parameters, I can cause it to have no *real* solutions.  Is there a way to check that the number of real solutions is nonzero? It doesn't have to be fast.  In fact, if I could turn the problem around and get a set of constraints on my parameters for which a real solution exists that would be great, but I'm not sure if that's even possible...

Comment: Once you have a Groebner basis, it is sometimes possible to see this directly from the polynomials in the Grobner basis, i.e., whether there is a real solution or not. For example, see the solution [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1786094/how-to-calculate-the-nullity-for-a-matrix-with-variable/1786103#1786103), where we have three real solutions.

Comment: Is it true that, in order to have a real solution to the original system, all polynomials in the Groebner basis must have real solutions?

Comment: The solution set of the Groebner basis polynomial system is the same as for the original system. If there is a real solution to the system of polynomials of the Groebner basis, then so it is for your system.

Comment: That's useful to know, but I guess it doesn't solve the original problem, since now I have to solve the same problem on a potentially larger Groebner basis.

Comment: No, the reduced Groebner basis could be much smaller, and sometimes all reduces to just one polynomial in one variable (see the above example). If you say you only have $6$ equations, I am sure it is possible. The whole point of a Groebner basis is to make things easier than in the original system.

Comment: Actually, do you have a (smaller) example of such equations ?

Comment: Actually, here are the equations in however many variables I wish:

$\sum_{i=1}^nx_{i1} = 0$

$\sum_{i=1}^nx_{i3}x_{i2} = 0$

$\sum_{i=1}^nx_{i1}x_{i3} = 0$

$\forall i \in [1,n]:$

$x_{i1}^2 + x_{i2}^2 = 1$

$x_{i3}^2 + x_{i4}^2 = 1$

$x_{i5}^2 + x_{i6}^2 = 1$

where each of the $n$ components contains 6 variables

Comment: I see. These are $3n+3$ equations, and not $6$ equations. I will try to solve it for small $n$ first.

Comment: Thanks.  I worked with n=2 and got approximately 12 polynomials in the Groebner basis.  With n = 3 I got an indecently large number and 611 parameters.  I am, however, using mupad for this, which seems to be lacking some refinement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system of polynomial equations you have given in the comments has $3n+3$ equations in $6n$ variables. For $n=2$ it has obvious real solutions (we do not need a Gröbner basis), namely
$$
x_{11}=1, x_{21}=-1, x_{14}=x_{24}=x_{16}=x_{26}=1, 
$$
and all other equal to zero. In general it seems we can do this. For which $n$ do you think that there is no real solution ?

Comment: Ah, I see.  I actually have two comments relating to this:  first, that is not the only solution in 2 variables.  In fact, the system is positive dimensional.  I was looking more for the parameterization of all solutions, I should have made that clear.  Second, I believe you are correct regarding always having real solutions.  However, I mis-typed the 3rd equation.  It should read:

$\sum_{i=1}^nx_{i1}x_{i3} = K$, where $K$ is a positive real number.  It is the addition of K that prevents the system from having real solutions for some values of K